# In delayed expression evaluation, R Shiny uses changed values of variables

Tags: r, shiny

Here is a simple demo of the problem:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textOutput("Text1"),
    textOutput("Text2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    for(i in 1:2) {
        id <- paste0("Text", i)
        output[[id]] <- renderText(paste0("This is text #", i)) # Problem!
    }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This program produces output

This is text #2
This is text #2

rather then #1 and #2.

Evidently, Shiny stores the expressions passed to `renderText()` in the line marked **# Problem!**, and evaluates them *after* the for-loop is finished. The expressions depend on variable `i`, and its final value `i = 2` is used in evaluating both expressions.

How can I produce correct output (how can I force Shiny to use different values of `i` in different expressions), while still using the loop? In my code the loop limits are dynamic, and I cannot replace the loop with several static calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why the `for`-loop does not work, check the output of this example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("Text1"),
  textOutput("Text2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  for(i in 1:3) {
    id <- paste0("Text", i)
    output[[id]] <- renderText(paste0("This is text #", i)) # Problem!
  }
  i=10 # we set i to 10.

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, all `renderText` elements use the last (global) value for i. This is not the case in the `lapply`, where an argument is passed to the function, but that argument is not defined in the global environment.

So you could use `lapply` instead of a `for`-loop, like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("Text1"),
  textOutput("Text2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  lapply(1:2,function(i){
    id <- paste0("Text", i)
    output[[id]] <- renderText(paste0("This is text #", i)) # Problem!
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you also want the ui to be reactive, you could use `renderUI` and `uiOutput`, for example as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("number_of_text","Number of text",min=1,max=10,value=3),
  uiOutput('my_text')
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  reactive_text <- reactive({
    all_text <- lapply(1:input$number_of_text,function(i){
      id <- paste0("Text", i)
      renderText(paste0("This is text #", i)) # Problem!
    })
   # do.call(all_text,tagList)
  })

  output$my_text <- renderUI({
    do.call(fluidRow, reactive_text())
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1. Wow, this was fast! Thanks!
2. Yes, I knew about dynamic UI, based on `RenderUI` and `uiOutput`. But it is nice to have explicit example right here.
3. Could you please explain WHY `lapply` behaves differently from the loop?

Comment: Hi Alex, I have added an explanation to the beginning of my answer. I hope that makes it clear.

Comment: OK, from your added explanation, I see that the magic is not in `lapply` but in placing call to `renderText` inside an auxiliary function. Indeed, this  code, not as elegant as with `lapply`, but works as well:

`foo <- function(i, output) {
    id <- paste0("Text", i);
    output[[id]] <- renderText(paste0("This is text #", i))
};

server <- function(input, output) {
    for(i in 1:2) {
        foo(i, output)
    }
}`

Comment: I'd argue that that solution is just as elegant, that's a pretty smart solution. Looks like I learned something as well ;)

Comment: FYI, I wrote a detailed explanation on *why* this happens here - https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-with-dynamic-number-of-datatables/2405/8

Comment: @greg
@Florian
Thanks greg, now I learned about `local` and `force`. I have never wandered into this part of R. Like! :)