# How to convert a Shiny app consisting of multiple files into an easily shareable and reproducible Shiny example?

Tags: r, shiny

There are resources on how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in general on Stack Overflow, and on [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However, there are no similar guidelines for [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) questions, while adhering to certain standards makes it much more likely that quality answers will be given, and thus that your question will be resolved.

However, asking a good Shiny question can be difficult. [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) apps are often large and complex, use multiple data sources, and the code is often split over multiple files, making it difficult to share easily reproducible code with others. Even though a problem may be caused in `server.R`, the example is not reproducible without the contents of `ui.R` (and possibly other files like stylesheets or `global.R`). Copy-pasting the contents of all these files individually is cumbersome, and requires other users to recreate the same file structure to be able to reproduce the problem.

So; how to convert your [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app into a good reproducible example?

Comment: Would this be a better question for [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Could be, but I might not be the best one to judge that since I rarely visit meta. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is pretty broad in its definition of 'good' questions for Stack Overflow. The reason I asked this question here is mainly just that similar questions regarding `r` and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) are also on Stack Overflow rather than on meta, so I assumed that was the right thing to do.

Comment: @Pac0 I do see your point - although I am not sure if I fully agree. Maybe it is a good idea to move this from the comments to a [discussion on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363046/where-should-how-to-create-a-good-reproducible-example-questions-reside) to also get the opinions of others regarding this question and possible future questions that are similar in nature.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Example data**

Of course, all guidelines regarding sample data mentioned in the answer on the question [“how to make a great R reproducible example”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/) also hold when creating questions related to `Shiny`. To summarize: Make sure no additional files are needed to run your code. Use sample datasets like `mtcars`, or create some sample data with `data.frame()`. If your data is very complex and that complexity is really required to illustrate the issue, you could also use `dput()`. Avoid using functions like `read.csv()`, unless of course you have questions related to functions like `fileInput`.

**Example code**

Always reduce your code to the bare minimum to reproduce your error or unexpected behavior. This includes removing calls to additional `.CSS` files and `.js` files and removing unnecessary functions in the `ui` and the `server`.

Shiny apps often consist of two or three files (`ui.R`, `server.R` and possibly `global.R`), for example [this demo application](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/kmeans-example.html). However, it is preferable to post your code as a single script, so it can easily be run by others without having to manually create those files. This can easily be done by:

- wrapping your ui with `ui <- fluidPage(…)`,
- the server with `server <- function(input,output, session) {…}`,
- and subsequently calling `shinyApp(ui, server)`.

So a simple skeleton to start with could look as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  )

server <- function(input,output,session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Working Example**

So, taking all the above into account, a good Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for a Shiny application could look as follows:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:10], value = seq(1,10))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput('nrow', 'Number of rows', min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
  dataTableOutput('my_table')
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    df[1:input$nrow,]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Adding CSS**

There are multiple ways to add custom CSS to a Shiny application, as explained [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). The preferred way to add CSS to a Shiny application in a reproducible example is to add the CSS in the code, rather than in a separate file. This can be done by adding a line in the `ui` of an application, for example as follows:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('body {background-color: lightblue;}'))),
```

Comment: I think the function `shinyUI` is obsolete and unnecessary.

Comment: @GyD, I think you are right, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Florian. Maybe you could address when the app required to load a file.

Comment: @MLavoie, good suggestion, I was hoping to capture that with "If your data is very complex and that complexity is really required to illustrate the issue, you could also use dput(). Avoid using functions like read.csv()..." Do you think that covers it, or were you thinking of something else?

Comment: Yes I think that will do.