# Add mouse coordinates in Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am working on a shiny application where a user clicks on a map (leaflet map) and based on that click, certain actions are being performed, like draw a circle of radius one km around the clicked point. This functionality works fine. However I want to add the mouse coordinates by using the `addMouseCoordinates()` function from the `mapview` package. I have used this in the past with no problems. However with the following code, I am unable to see the coordinates.

```
leafletProxy('incidentmap') %>%
      addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                 weight=1, radius=input$radius, color='black', fillColor='green',
                 fillOpacity=0.2, opacity=1)%>%
      addCircles(lng=filtered$Long,lat=filtered$Lat)%>%
      addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic")
```

Now if I click on the map, the application crashes with the following error:

```
> Warning: Error in : inherits(map, "leaflet") is not TRUE Stack trace
> (innermost first):
>     75: stopifnot
>     74: addMouseCoordinates
>     73: function_list[[k]]
>     72: withVisible
>     71: freduce
>     70: _fseq
>     69: eval
>     68: eval
>     67: withVisible
>     66: %>%
>     65: observeEventHandler [/Users/dhirajkhanna/Desktop/CallAnalysis/CDR/server.R#39]
>      1: runApp ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

Has it got something to do with `leafletProxy()` ?
Help would be appreciated.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("incidentmap")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$incidentmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = 77.9568288, lat = 27.1696145, zoom=11) %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE))
  })
    ## Observe mouse clicks and add circles
    observeEvent(input$incidentmap_click, {
      click <- input$incidentmap_click
      clat <- click$lat
      clng <- click$lng

      leafletProxy('incidentmap') %>%
        addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                   weight=1, radius=1000, color='black', fillColor='green',
                   fillOpacity=0.2, opacity=1)%>%
                   addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please consider adding a reproducible example to your question, that makes it much easier to help. For some tips on how to do that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable).

Comment: Thanks @Florian for pointing to this. Have included a reproducible example now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when you move the `addMouseCoordinates` call to where the map is set up (where you define `output$incidentmap`)

```
library(shiny)
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("incidentmap")
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  output$incidentmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(lng = 77.9568288, lat = 27.1696145, zoom=11) %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic")
  })
  ## Observe mouse clicks and add circles
  observeEvent(input$incidentmap_click, {
    click <- input$incidentmap_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng

    leafletProxy('incidentmap') %>%
      addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                 weight=1, radius=1000, color='black', fillColor='green',
                 fillOpacity=0.2, opacity=1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @TimSalabim

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to fill your need. You can easily improve uppon it ..

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map1 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%  addTiles() 
  })

  observeEvent(input$map1_click, {

    click <- input$map1_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng
    content <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
                     "<b>",clat, "</b>",
                     "<b>", clng, "</b>"    )
    leafletProxy('map1') %>% 
      addCircles(lng=clng, lat=clat, group='circles',
                 weight=1, radius=100, color='black', fillColor='orange',
                 fillOpacity=0.5, opacity=1)  %>% 
      addPopups(lng = clng, lat = clat, content)

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @MrSmithGoesToWashington but not quite. Your code will show the lat long of the place that has been clicked. However the user generally has the lat long of the place they wish to click already available. Hence they need to hover with the mouse to that place and then click.

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear for me from your question.What do you mean by "the user generally has the lat long of the place ..." ? Is it shown in your reproductible example ?

Comment: the user receives the location of a point verbally and has to use the mouse to hover to that location on the map and click. Its not possible to show this through an example.