# Unable to display Shiny output in specified tabs

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

I am trying to make a simple shiny app that takes information from a csv file and produces a table and two graphs.  The content appears to be loading correctly but I can not seem to get the output to go within the specified tab, making the output appear cluttered and difficult to read. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plater)
server <- function(input, output) {


output$table1 <- renderTable({

req(input$file1)

df <- read_plate(input$file1$datapath)

if(input$disp == "head") {
  return(head(df))
}
else {
  return(df)
}

data <- reactive({
  read_plate(input$file1$datapath)
})


})



{output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
req(input$file1)

df <- read_plate(input$file1$datapath)


ggplot(df, aes(x=Column, y=Row, size = 20, color = "variabley")) + geom_point()


})



}

output$vx <- renderUI({
req(input$file1)

df <- read_plate(input$file1$datapath)
selectInput("variablex", "Select the (X) Variable", choices = names(df))
})

output$vy <- renderUI({
req(input$file1)

df <- read_plate(input$file1$datapath)
selectInput("variabley", "Select the (y) Variable", choices = names(df))
})

output$p <- renderPlot({
req(input$file1)

df <- read_plate(input$file1$datapath)
ggplot(df, aes(input$variablex, input$variabley, size = 20)) + geom_point()
  })
  }

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Enrichment Analysis"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv")),


  tags$hr(),

  # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
  checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

  # Input: Select separator ----
  radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
               choices = c(Comma = ",",
                           Semicolon = ";",
                           Tab = "\t"),
               selected = ","),

  # Input: Select quotes ----
  radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
               choices = c(None = "",
                           "Double Quote" = '"',
                           "Single Quote" = "'"),
               selected = '"'),
  #Checkbox


  # Horizontal line ----
  tags$hr(),

  # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
  radioButtons("disp", "Display",
               choices = c(Head = "head",
                           All = "all"),
               selected = "head")

),






mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
              tabPanel("Plot", fluid = TRUE,
                       sidebarLayout(
                         sidebarPanel(selectInput("colm", "Variable", choices = names(df), selected = "")),
                         mainPanel(
                           plotOutput("Plot1")
                         )
                       )
              ),



              tabPanel("Plate"),
                  sidebarPanel(
                   uiOutput("vx"),
                   uiOutput("vy"),
                     mainPanel(plotOutput("p", width = "70%"))
              ),

              tabPanel("Comparison"),
              tabPanel("Table")),




  tableOutput("table1")

)

  )

)

shinyApp(ui, server )
```

Comment: We can't run your code. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first post, what is the problem with the input?

Comment: We need to load a file (we don't have) to run your code

Comment: The file being uploaded utilizes the plater package in R to convert a 96 well plate (12 columns by  rows)  into a data frame.  I'm not sure if that answers your question but there does not seem to be a way to file share directly

Comment: Hi @gcjohn49, please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable/48343110#48343110) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/), that may help you simplify your question. You can try and remove the reference and use of the plater package, just use for example `mtcars`. If your issue persists; great, your example has become smaller. If your problem disappears; it is probably the plater package and you can specify that in your question.