# To reduce the font of all the elements of sidebarpanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Below is the part of UI code.I am not able to see all the selectinput in the sidebarpanel,
i suspect,it is not able to scroll further or may be if the font size of the 
sidebarpanel has to be reduced.Any different approach which can be implemented to solve the problem?

```
dashboardPage(title = "title",
  dashboardHeader(title="title1"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                      .selectize-input, .selectize-dropdown {
                        font-size:40%;
                        }                     }
                        "))), 

   radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type",choices=c("csv file","xlsx file")),  


   tags$div(title="Date format should be mm/dd/YYYY",fileInput("file1", "Upload Data File", accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv",".xlsx",".xls"))),   

   uiOutput("col"),
   uiOutput("covariate"),
   uiOutput("dimensions1"),
   uiOutput("levels1"),
   uiOutput("dimensions2"),
   uiOutput("level2"),
   uiOutput("dimensions3"),
   uiOutput("level3"),
   uiOutput("dimensions4"),
   uiOutput("level4")


               ),
  dashboardBody(tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".my_class {
                      font-weight: bold;
                      color:white;
                      }")
      ))
    ,uiOutput("All_tab_Display")


  )
)
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but I was unable to. Could you please [add a reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better provide a reproducible example of your work.
test this and notify me whether it helped or not:

```
 tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .sidebar { height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; font-size: 10px;}
                      " )
      )
    )
```

Comment: I have edited the code.@Mahdi,I used your mentioned tag,it works,but strange thing is when the app is ran on laptop without a external mouse,the scroll does not work.

Comment: then try this: overflow-y: scroll;

Comment: Well,the issue still persists.If somehow i can reduce the font size of all the elements of sidebarpanel, It may work.

Comment: Updated the code. Try different font sizes to reach your goal

Comment: Great!! Works now.Thanks Mahdi!!

Comment: Any time ;). Do not forget to vote for the answer, so others can find it easier in case of emergency!