# R Shiny Creating Reactive (Single) Plot from Multiple User Inputs

Tags: r, plot, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive

The goal is to create an interactive (Single) plot that the user can select
the year of interest, the status of the member, and the service of interest 
and each will select the correct data point. Each x,y coordinate is the 
mean satisfaction and mean importance respectively. I have it working with 
just the services (plot colm), but Id like to be able to have the user 
have more selection. My attempt for multiple inputs is plotOutput("test")..

Any ideas how to get this code working?? THANK YOU!!

UI:

```
importance <- c(4.25, 3.08)
satisfaction <- c(3.90, 3.18)
dfGap <- data.frame(importance, satisfaction)

imp.A <- c("3.2","2.5","3.3","4.5","4","3.7")
sat.b <- c("2.2", "3.7","5","1.2","2.6","3")
yr.c <- c("2016","2016","2017","2016", "2016","2017")
status.d <- c("Student", "Not","Student", "Not","Student","Student")
service.e <- c("Huddle", "Web", "Test", "Web","Other","Huddle")

dfTest <- data.frame(imp.A,sat.b,yr.c,status.d, service.e)



colDepend = ("darkred")
range <- c("2016"=1,"2017"=2)
choices <- c("Web" = 1,"Huddle" = 2, "Other" = 3, "Test" = 4)
role <- c("Student" = 1, "Not" = 2)


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)


    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title="Membership Satisfaction"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Value Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = 
    icon("dashboard")),
         menuItem("Services Dashboard", tabName = "service", icon = 
    icon("dashboard")),
        menuItem("Demographics Dashboard", tabName = "demos", icon = 
    icon("dashboard"))
       )
       ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "service",
            sidebarPanel(checkboxGroupInput("vars","Select variables to 
    plot", choices = choices)),
              fluidPage(
                plotOutput("colm"),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                br(),
                h6(strong("Gap Analysis: Plot points calculated as mean 
                 importance and mean satisfaction."),
               style = "font-family:'calibri"),
                br(),
                br(),
                h6(strong("Strength: These are the primary strengths. We are 
       meeting highly important services with high satisfaction."),
               style = "font-family:'calibri"),
            h6(strong("Potential Advantages: Member satisfaction is being 
        met, however these services may not be as important for brand 
        equity."),
               style = "font-family:'calibri"),
            h6(strong("Secondary Opportunitites: These services are not 
            crucial (not highly important) and should not be a primary 
            focus."),
               style = "font-family:'calibri"),
            h6(strong("Target Issues: Targeting efforts here can improve 
              membership. These are services that are highly important 
               however are not meeting needs of members."),
               style = "font-family:'calibri")
          )),
      tabItem(tabName = "demos",
          sidebarPanel(
            checkboxGroupInput("inpt","Select variables to plot", choices = 
                 choices),
            checkboxGroupInput("role", 
                               "Select Primary Role of Interest", 
                               choices = role),
            checkboxGroupInput("yrs", 
                               "Select year(S) of Interest", 
                               choices = range)),
          fluidPage(

            plotOutput("test")

          )


      ))

  )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input,output){
  output$matrixValue<- renderTable({
    matrixValue
  },include.rownames=TRUE)

  output$matrixRENEW<- renderTable({
    matrixRENEW
    },include.rownames=TRUE)


  output$value_BP <- renderPlot({
    barplot(matrixValue, beside = T,
          legend.text=rownames(matrixValue),
          args.legend=list(x="topleft"),
          main = titleValue,col=cols)})

  output$renew_BP<- renderPlot({
    barplot(matrixRENEW, beside = T,
          legend.text=rownames(matrixRENEW),
          args.legend=list(x="topleft"),
          main = titleRENEW,col=cols)})


  output$colm <- (renderPlot({
    ggplot(dfGap[input$vars,], aes(satisfaction,importance))+ 
    theme(text=element_text(size=12))+
    geom_point(colour =input$vars, shape = 17, size=5 )+ 
    labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") + 
    xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)+
    annotate("text", x = 4.8, y = 5, 
           label = "Strengths", 
           color = "chartreuse4",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
   annotate("text", x = .3, y = 5, 
           label = "Target Issues", 
           color = "firebrick4",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
   annotate("text", x = .78, y = 0, 
           label = "Secondary Opportunities", 
           color = "dodgerblue3",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
   annotate("text", x = 4.4, y = 0, 
           label = "Potential Advantages", 
           color = "grey10",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)

  }))






  output$test <- renderPlot({

   ggplot(dfTest[service.e[service.e==input$inpt,],], aes(imp.A,sat.b))+ 
    theme(text=element_text(size=12))+
    geom_point(colour ="green", shape = 17, size=5 )+ 
    labs(x = "Mean Satisfaction", y = "Mean Importance") + 
    xlim(0,5) + ylim(0,5)+
    geom_vline(xintercept=2.5) + geom_hline(yintercept =  2.5)+
    annotate("text", x = 4.8, y = 5, 
           label = "Strengths", 
           color = "chartreuse4",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
    annotate("text", x = .3, y = 5, 
           label = "Target Issues", 
           color = "firebrick4",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
    annotate("text", x = .78, y = 0, 
           label = "Secondary Opportunities", 
           color = "dodgerblue3",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)+
    annotate("text", x = 4.4, y = 0, 
           label = "Potential Advantages", 
           color = "grey10",
           style = "font-family:'calibri", 
           size =6.5,
           fontface =2)})


}



shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

The service tab is working how I'd like the demos tab to work, I'm just struggling with getting the different user inputs to map to a plot in a similar way. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are accessing variables which hasn't be defined. Make sure your code works so that others can help you.  Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable) to know how to create a reproducible shiny example.

Comment: This should work now!