# R Shiny App Error - Couldn't Find Any UI

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote this code and initially Shiny worked just fine and the app started:

```
library(shiny)    
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", min = 0, max = 100,
                value = c(25,40), pre = "$")
  ),
  mainPanel("Results")
)
```

But when I add any UI element to it, for example radioButton:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", min = 0, max = 100,
                value = c(25,40), pre = "$"),
    radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
                 choices = c("p1", "p2", "p3"),
                 selected = "p1")
  ),
  mainPanel("Results")
)
```

I get an error:

```
Shiny couldn't find any UI for this application. We looked in:    
www/index.html
ui.R
app.R
```

Any idea what might cause this? I tried other options instead of a radio button and received the same error. My server file is just an empty file with the server function.

Comment: how did you run app? and you should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask but I ran it on R studio console and browser too. could you please elaborate on provide a reproducible example?

Comment: see that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable

Answer (score 1):

Add the elements inside a `sidebarLayout(...)`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", min = 0, max = 100,
            value = c(25,40), pre = "$"),
         radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
             choices = c("p1", "p2", "p3"),
             selected = "p1")),ț
    )
    mainPanel("main panel")
  )
)
```

Comment: From what I read we don't need a shinyApp(ui, server) when we use 2 files, right?

Comment: Yep, but two files names `ui.R` and `server.R`

Comment: Yes. I have that too

Comment: And do you have the `ui <- fluidPage(...` code in the `ui.R` file?

Comment: yes, I have that. It works fine with 1 UI element but the moment I add another one it crashes.

Comment: I get the same error as before: Worked with just sliderInput() but after adding another element got the same error.
`fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", min = 0, max = 100,
                  value = c(25,40), pre = "$"),
      radioButtons("typeInput", "Product type",
                   choices = c("p1", "p2", "p3"),
                   selected = "p1")
    ),
    mainPanel("Main Panel") 
  )
)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169886/discussion-between-teodor-ciuraru-and-digvijay-sawant).

Comment: Did you find the answer to your problem? I am experiencing the exact same issue.