# How to play audio files in Shiny if no path/source is known?

Tags: r, audio, shiny

For a Shiny app, I want to be able to play audio files that are generated during the session itself.
If it were an audio-file that I want to upload, I would use

```
    tags$audio(src = "www/name.wav", type = "audio/wav")
```

However, I could not find a way to use tags$audio if the audio file is generated during the session, and thus I do not have a filename or path.
Any suggestions on how I can play such audio files? Thanks!

EDIT: I added a short reproducible example. Hopefully it becomes more clear what I am trying to do.

```
    url <- "http://www.wavlist.com/humor/001/911d.wav"

    # Define the temporary directory and download the data
    dest_path <- "sound.wav"
    download.file(url,destfile = dest_path)

    # Load the audio file
    test <- audio::load.wave(dest_path)

    # Change something small to this audio file
    test <- test + 0.3
```

My question now is how can I play "test" using `tags$audio(src = "", type = "audio/wav")`, without having a path for the `src = ""` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to copy the generated file to the `www` folder, and use `renderUI` to create your audio tag. Below is an example on how you could achieve that. Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(audio)
library(seewave)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('my_url','URL:',value="http://www.wavlist.com/humor/001/911d.wav"),
  uiOutput('my_audio')
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  # Render the audio player
  output$my_audio <- renderUI({

    url <- input$my_url

    # Define the temporary directory and download the data
    dest_path <- "sound.wav"
    download.file(url,destfile = dest_path)
    # Load the audio file
    test <- audio::load.wave(dest_path)
    # Change something small to this audio file
    test <- test + 0.3
    savewav(test,filename = 'www/myaudio.wav')

      tags$audio(id='my_audio_player',
                 controls = "controls",
                 tags$source(
                   src = markdown:::.b64EncodeFile('www/myaudio.wav'),
                   type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis'))

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Florian! It does push me in the right direction (I think), but the problem I am now facing is the following: I am generating an audio-variable (which is basically a list of doubles), so I do not have the datapath of it, and thus I cannot use file.copy(from, to). Any suggestions on how I could "download" this audio-variable to the www folder?

Comment: @AES, if you are looking for a more specific answer, please consider creating a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable/48343110). I am not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: I added a reproducible example. My apologies! :)

Comment: @AES, I modified my example to closer match your desired behavior. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Yep it helped! Thanks a lot!