# Absolute panel in R shiny gets hidden behind the leaflet output

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I am trying to make a leaflet map full screen and also add filter controls on top of the map. However, when I try to do this my filter control(absolute panel) gets hidden behind the leaflet output during runtime.

[Absolute panel is present when I give width manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5P9N.png)

I want the map to be full-screen , when I do it, [it gets hidden behind the map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uTHV.jpg)

How can I make the map go behind the absolute panel?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Below is the UI code:

```
fluidPage(style="padding-top: 10px;",
      h1("Locations"),
      absolutePanel(
        top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
        width = 330, height = "auto",draggable = TRUE,
        wellPanel(
          selectInput("Suburb", "Select one Suburb:",choices = c("Select one Suburb" = "All", as.character(mydata$SuburbTown))),
          uiOutput("secondselection")
          ),
        style = "opacity: 0.65"
          ),

      leafletOutput("leafl", height = "800px")
          )
```

Comment: Hi @Karan, at the moment, the provided code does not suffice to reproduce the behavior you mention. It would help if you could add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable) to your question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since today, after updating all packages (including leaflet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the `z-index` of your panel to make it work.
Try this:

```
fluidPage(style="padding-top: 10px;",
      h1("Locations"),
      absolutePanel(
        top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
        width = 330, height = "auto",draggable = TRUE,
        wellPanel(
          selectInput("Suburb", "Select one Suburb:",choices = c("Select one Suburb" = "All", as.character(mydata$SuburbTown))),
          uiOutput("secondselection")
        ),
        style = "opacity: 0.65; z-index: 10;" ## z-index modification
      ),

      leafletOutput("leafl", height = "800px")
)
```

Comment: @Forever It worked for me once but after I restarted my app I'm having the same issue. I tried to use it in a .css file as well but no luck

Comment: @Karan Kumar, try this instead: `z-index: 10 !important ;`. If it does not work, please consider sharing a reproducible example.

Comment: @Forever "z-index: 1000;"  worked for me as well. Thank you, guys!!

Comment: @kluu  [z-index: 10 ! important ;] did not work in css as well but  using [z-index: 1000] worked, either you include it in css file or in UI file , it worked both the ways

Answer (score 0):

just rewrite it,
     send it top of absolutePanel     leafletOutput("leafl", height = "800px")

```
fluidPage(style="padding-top: 10px;",
  h1("Locations"),
  leafletOutput("leafl", height = "800px"),
  absolutePanel(
    top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
        width = 330, height = "auto",draggable = TRUE,
        wellPanel(
          selectInput("Suburb", "Select one Suburb:",choices = c("Select one Suburb" = 
"All", as.character(mydata$SuburbTown))),
          uiOutput("secondselection")
          ),`enter code here`
        style = "opacity: 0.65"
              )
      )
```