# How to make leaflet map and absolutePanel of inputs / outputs full screen in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I want to click a button to make a leaflet map and all overlayed inputs full screen.

Using the following example, I can make the map full screen but I lose the inputs (in this case, `h1("test")`). Or I can preserve the inputs on top of the map but then the map is not drawn full screen as expected.

```r
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}"



ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$scrip(HTML(js)),
  actionButton("fullscreen", "Full Screen Container",
               onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('map_container'))"),
  actionButton("fullscreen", "Full Screen Map Only",
               onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('map'))"),
  div(
    id = "map_container",
    leafletOutput(height = "100px", "map"),
    absolutePanel(
      top = 20,
      right = 20,
      h1("test", style = "color:white")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>% 
      setView(lng = 118.2437, lat = 34.0522, zoom = 5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Update**

I tried adding `z-index: 10000 !important;` to the `h1()` style based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114785/9489566), but it is still hidden when maximizing the leaflet map.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991329/leaflet-fullscreen-toggle-button-in-r-shiny/70994128#70994128

Comment: Looking at the gif provided in the answer, it doesn’t look like the inputs are overlayed on top of the map in full screen. That is the issue. I can already make the leaflet map itself full screen. That is demonstrated by the reprex I included in my question. I want to make the map and inputs on top of the map full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

js <- "
function openFullscreen(elem) {
  var map = $(elem).find('.leaflet.html-widget');
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
  $(map).css('height', '100vh').trigger('resize');
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);

function exitHandler(){
  if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement) return;
  $('#map').css('height', '400px').trigger('resize');
}
 
"



ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton(
        "fullscreen", "Full Screen Container",
         onclick = "openFullscreen(document.getElementById('map_container'))"
    ),
    div(
        id = "map_container",
        leafletOutput(height = "400px", "map"),
        absolutePanel(
            top = 20,
            right = 20,
            style = "color: #FFF",
            h1("test", style = "color:white"),
            selectInput("in2", "choose", 1:5),
            numericInput("in3", "number", 0, 0, 10)
        )
    ),
    tags$scrip(HTML(js))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% 
            addProviderTiles('Esri.WorldImagery') %>% 
            setView(lng = 118.2437, lat = 34.0522, zoom = 5)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Explain:

1. If you want the controls to also be in the full screen, we need to full screen the container, not just the map.
2. The leaflet map has a fixed height `400px` so in fullscreen, first change its height to max screen height `100vh`. This is not enough for the leaflet to adjust the map, we also need to fire the `resize` event.
3. When users change fullscreen status, we need to resize the map back to the original size. To do so, we use `addEventListener` to watch screen change event. Depends on the browser, the event name is different, but we attach the same callback `exitHandler`.
4. `exitHandler` first checks on different browsers, if we are on full screen or normal screen. If normal screen, resize the map to the original size.

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you. Can you briefly explain the JS code additions?

Comment: @GiovanniColitti see edits