# shiny multiple selection chart update

Tags: r, shiny

i have a problem with my shiny app which won't update barchart when using multiple selection. It generates only chart on specified data at the beginning. Adding update button doesn't work

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(

      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sele", label = "Wyznania (do wykresu slupkowego):", choiceValues = dane_3, choiceNames = nazwy_3,
                         selected = dane_3),
      actionButton("update", "Update View")

    ),

    mainPanel(

      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                 [..]
                  tabPanel("Wykres slupkowy", plotOutput("barPlot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  sele2 <- reactive({
  return(as.vector(as.numeric(input$sele)))
  })

  output$barPlot <- renderPlot({
    dane_new = as.matrix(as.numeric(dane_3[as.numeric(sele2())]))
    nazwy_new = nazwy_3[as.numeric(sele2())]
    rownames(dane_new) = nazwy_new

    barchart(dane_new,xlab="Sredni wynik egzaminu SAT")

  })
[..]      
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

Comment: I suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable

Comment: `dane_3` in the `barchart` command is not connected to a reactive data element anywhere.

Comment: sorry, should be dane_new, which also doesn't work