# Hide/Show table in R shiny based on input value

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to show/hide a table based on the input selection. Based on my first dropdown if the user selects a value wave2 it should show the table 2 under the 1st tab else it should hide. I tried to use the react input select value to if else condition for output which is not how react works in R. Could someone please check and let me know on where I am wrong .

UI.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinythemes)

dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = F, title = "PATH Study"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("choose_wave"),
    uiOutput("choose_category"),
    uiOutput("choose_ethnicity"),
    uiOutput("choose_age"),
    uiOutput("choose_gender")
  ),
  #S dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(), sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),body,title = NUll, skin = "yellow"),
  dashboardBody(box(
    width = 12,
    tabBox(
      width = 12,
      id = "tabBox_next_previous",
      tabPanel("Initiation",
               fluidRow(
                 box(
                   title = "TABLE1",
                   width = 5,
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   status = "primary",
                   tableOutput("smoke"),
                   collapsible = T,

                 ),
                 box(
                   title = "TABLE2",
                   width = 7,
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   status = "primary",
                   tableOutput("first_flov"),
                   collapsible = T
                 )
                  ))
    ),
    uiOutput("Next_Previous")
  ))
)
```

SERVER.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  print(sessionInfo())

  with_demo_vars <- reactive({
    data_selector(wave(), youth()) %>%
      mutate(
        ethnicity = !!ethnicity(),
        age = !!age_group(),
        gender = !!gender()
      )
  })
  # Drop-down selection box for which Wave and User Type bracket to be selected
  output$choose_wave <- renderUI({
    # This can be static: it is the highest level and the options won't change
    selectInput(
      "selected_wave",
      "Wave",
      choices = list(
        "Wave 1 Adult" = "wave1youthFALSE",
        "Wave 1 Youth" = "wave1youthTRUE",
        "Wave 2 Adult" = "wave2youthFALSE",
        "Wave 2 Youth" = "wave2youthTRUE"
      )
    )
  })

  wave <- reactive({
    as.integer(gsub("wave(\\d)youth.*", "\\1", input$selected_wave))
  })

  youth <- reactive({
    as.logical(gsub("wave\\dyouth(.+)$", "\\1", input$selected_wave))
  })


  # Drop-down selection box for which Gender bracket to be selected
  output$choose_ethnicity <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_ethnicity", "Ethnicity", as.list(levels(with_demo_vars()$ethnicity)))
  })
  # Drop-down selection box for which Age bracket to be selected
  output$choose_age <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_age", "Age", as.list(levels(with_demo_vars()$age)))
  })
  # Drop-down selection box for which Gender bracket to be selected
  output$choose_gender <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selected_gender", "Gender", as.list(levels(with_demo_vars()$gender)))
  })

  output$selected_var <- renderText({
    paste("You have selected", input$selected_wave)
  })

    myData <- reactive({
    # wave_selected <- input$selected_wave
    category_selected <- req(input$selected_category)
    age_selected <- req(input$selected_age)
    gender_selected <- req(input$selected_gender)
    ethnicity_selected <- req(input$selected_ethnicity)

    # TABLE 1
    df<-data_selector(wave = 1, youth()) %>%
      filter(!!is_ever_user(type = category_selected)) %>%
      pct_first_flavored(type = category_selected)
    df_sub <- names(df) %in% c("variable")
    df <- df[!df_sub]

    df
      })

  first_flov <- reactive({
    category_selected <- req(input$selected_category)
    age_selected <- req(input$selected_age)
    gender_selected <- req(input$selected_gender)
    ethnicity_selected <- req(input$selected_ethnicity)

    first_flov_df <- data_selector(wave = 2, youth()) %>%
      filter(!!is_new_user(type = category_selected)) %>%  # this doesn't apply to wave 1
      pct_first_flavored(type = category_selected)

    first_flov_df_sub <- names(first_flov_df) %in% c("variable")
    first_flov_df <- first_flov_df[!first_flov_df_sub]
    first_flov_df
      })
  output$smoke <-
    renderTable({
      head(myData())
    })
  output$first_flov <-
        if (wave() == 2) {
      renderTable({
        head(first_flov())
      })
    } else {
      renderText({
        paste("You have selected", input$selected_wave)
      })
    }

})
```

Comment: Probably using a combination of `observeEvent` and `show` and `hide` from the shinyjs package can help you with that, see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/visibilityFuncs.html). Furthermore, your example is a bit large, making it more difficult to help. Please see [How to make a Shiny app reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080) for some tips on how to make a reproducible example for Shiny.

Comment: Take a look at [conditionalPanel](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/conditionalPanel.html)