# How to pass a reactive integer to a Shiny Dashboard with R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to pass a simple integer to a Shiny Flexdashboard. But I can for some reason only to it staticly, but I'd rather have it reactivly;

```
aggregated_static <- readRDS( "../rdsdata/aggregated_static.rds")
k <- nrow(aggregated_static)
```

That piece of code passes the number of rows to my Shiny dash, where it can be accessed with;

```
item_lines = k
```

But, if I do it this way, it won't work, telling me I can't access reactive content from that spot;

```
set_aggregated <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session,  "./rdsdata/set_aggregated.rds", readRDS)
k <- nrow(aggregated_static())
```

*Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)*

Now I've tried using Isolate, creating a function enclosing that with reactive({}), but I am simply nog getting that value passed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can define k and used as `data <- reactivevalues(k=0)`; `data$k <-nrow(...)`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, that will allow others to help you much better. See [How to make a Shiny app reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080) for some tips on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of `k` to be reactive, you should wrap it in `reactive()`, i.e.:

```
k <- reactive(nrow(aggregated_static()))
```

and then call its value as `k()`

Comment: I've tried the code provided, but that gives the same error


`set_aggregated <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session,  "./rdsdata/hub_set_aggregated.rds", readRDS)`

and then 

`k <- reactive(nrow(set_aggregated()))`

Comment: Is everything defined within your server function? If not, please see my comment on the question and provide a reproducible example and I'll have another look.