# R Shiny conditional panel issues

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, panel

My conditional panel is exhibiting weird behavior. I just want it to show respective table based on choice as it supposed to, however it only shows first table twice irrespective of choice and only first time it reaches correct node of if else statement. Afterwards it always end up in wrong if statement which concerns the part when rhandsontable inputs are changed.. I would highly appreciate your advice how to solve it. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

get_pct_table<-function(){
  rev_pct <-  data.frame(matrix(rnorm(0), ncol = 5, nrow = 3))
  col_names <- c("2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
  row_names <- c("Worst", "Base", "Best")
  rownames(rev_pct) <- row_names
  colnames(rev_pct) <-col_names 
  return(rev_pct)
}

get_pm_table<-function() {pm <-  data.frame(matrix(rnorm(0), ncol = 5, nrow = 3))
col_names <- c("Product","Quantity", "Avg. Price", "Avg. Cost", "Year")
colnames(pm) <- col_names
return(pm)
}


ui <- fluidPage("Lm Assumptions",

                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    radioButtons("lm_forecast_choice", "Lm Forecasting Method",
                                 c("Percentage Change"="pc", "Product Mix"="pm")
                    )
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.lm_forecast_choice == 'pc'",
                                     rHandsontableOutput("lm_forecast_c")
                    ),
                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.lm_forecast_choice == 'pm'",
                                     rHandsontableOutput("lm_forecast_m")
                    )


                  )
                )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  v = reactiveValues()   

  rev.choice <- reactive ({input$lm_forecast_choice})

  observe({


    if(!is.null(rev.choice())) {

      if(rev.choice()=="pc"){

        if (!is.null(input$lm_forecast_c)) {

          print("at pc changed")

          v$lm_forecast <- hot_to_r(input$lm_forecast_c)
        } else {    

          print("at pc new")

          v$lm_forecast <- get_pct_table()


        }
      }

      else if(rev.choice() == "pm"){

        if (!is.null(input$lm_forecast_m)) {

          print("at pm changed")

          v$lm_forecast <- hot_to_r(input$lm_forecast_m)
        } else {    

          print("at pm new")

          v$lm_forecast <- get_pm_table()

        }
      }

    }


  })




  output$lm_forecast_c <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(v$lm_forecast, rowHeaderWidth = 100) %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[1], format = "0%") %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[2], format = "0%") %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[3], format = "0%") %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[4], format = "0%") %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[5], format = "0%") %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = 90) %>%
      hot_rows(rowHeights = 30)

  })

  output$lm_forecast_m <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(v$lm_forecast, rowHeaderWidth = 100) %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[1], format = "$0,0.00") %>%
      hot_col(colnames(v$lm_forecast)[2], format = "$0,0.00") %>%
      hot_cols(colWidths = 90) %>%
      hot_rows(rowHeights = 30)

  })

}




# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Formatting your example code and making sure it is minimal and easily reproducible makes it easier to help you. See e.g. [How to make a Shiny app reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080) for tips on how to do this.

Comment: *Do not use dots in the input names!* The dot has a meaning in Javascript (it's somehow the same as `$` for lists in R). If you use a dot like `xx.yy` then `input.xx.yy` will not refer to `input$xx.yy`.

Comment: I removed dots from input names, yet still the same issue. Please kindly advise how to solve it. Thank you.