# Converting atomic vector to plot dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a shiny app that plots a heatmap based on compnay income and stuff and when that heatmap is plotted it should plot another graph depending on the user plot_click.

The complete code

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(gplots)
    library(plotly)
Comp_name <- c("Dum1")
Inc <- c(175.26,175.365,175.65,176.65,176.165,176.1685,175.56)
Exp <- c(175.48,174.53,174.165,173.1651,175.651,174.16541,176.65)
Date <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name,Inc,Exp,Date,Dates))
Comp_name1 <- c("Dum2")
Inc1 <- c(151.26,151.59,151.23,152.46,152.49,151.29,150.81)
Exp1 <- c(152.64,152.84,152.64,152.48,152.35,154.26,153.14)
Date1 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates1 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name1,Inc1,Exp1,Date1,Dates1))
Comp_name2 <- c("Dum3")
Inc2 <- c(160.45,161.25,163.56,165.25,163.59,160.89,161.26)
Exp2 <- c(160.19,160.78,162.15,164.89,165.24,163.25,162.48)
Date2 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates2 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name2,Inc2,Exp2,Date2,Dates2))
Comp_name3 <- c("Dum4")
Inc3 <- c(156.26,155.12,157.12,158.78,154.26,160.12,161.26)
Exp3 <- c(160.19,160.19,155.19,154.26,150.12,157.26,159.12)
Date3 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates3 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name3,Inc3,Exp3,Date3,Dates3))
Data <- cbind(Dummy1,Dummy2,Dummy3,Dummy4)
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)

ui <- fluidPage(
      tags$style(type="text/css",
             ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
             ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
  ),
  titlePanel("Creating a database"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Company Name"),
      numericInput("income", "Income", value = 1),
      numericInput("expenditure", "Expenditure", value = 1),
      dateInput("date", h3("Date input"),value = Sys.Date() ,min = "0000-01-01",
                max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd/mm/yy"),
      actionButton("Action", "Submit"), #Submit Button
      actionButton("new", "New")),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Download",
                           textInput("filename", "Enter Filename for download"),   #filename
                           helpText(strong("Warning: Append if want to update existing data.")),
                           downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'), #Button to save the file
                           downloadButton('Appenddata', 'Append')),#Button to update a file )
                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           actionButton("filechoose", "Choose File"),
                           br(),
                           selectInput("toplot", "To Plot", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                       "Compare Income And 
                                                                       Expenditure" = "cmp1",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit1",
                                                                       "Profit Lost" = "plost1",
                                                                       "Profit Percent" = "pp1",
                                                                       "Profit Trend" = "proftrend1"
                           )),
                           actionButton("plotit", "PLOT"),
                           plotOutput("Plot")),
                    tabPanel("Heatmap",
                           actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                           selectInput("ploth","Heatmap", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc2",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp2",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit2",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit2")),
                           actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                           plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                          fixedRow(column(3,actionButton("retable","Show Table")),
                                   column(3,actionButton("clear","Clear"))),  
                           tableOutput("click"),
                           plotOutput("Next")
                           )
                  )
      )

    )
  )
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()
  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 as.character(input$date),
                                 as.character(Sys.Date())))

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) #Append the row in the dataframe
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the output in the table
  })

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    Data <<- NULL
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })

  observeEvent(input$filechoose, {
    Data <<- read.csv(file.choose()) #Choose file to plot
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the choosen file details
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename , ".csv", sep="")}, # Create the download file name
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Data, file,row.names = FALSE) # download data
    })

  output$Appenddata <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename, ".csv", sep="")}, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.table( Data, file=file.choose(),append = T, sep=',',
                   row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE) # Append data in existing
    })

  observeEvent(input$plotit, {
    inc <- c(Data[ ,2]) 
    exp <- c(Data[ ,3]) 
    date <- c(Data[,4])
    gprofit <- c(Data[ ,2]- Data[ ,3])
    nprofit <- c(gprofit - (gprofit*0.06))
    z <- as.numeric(nrow(Data))
    plost <- gprofit - nprofit
    pp <- (gprofit/inc) * 100
    proftrend <- c(gprofit[2:z]-gprofit[1:(z-1)])
    slope = c(((proftrend[2:(z-1)]-proftrend[1:(z-2)])/1),0)
    y = input$toplot
    switch(EXPR = y ,
           inc = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= inc))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Income")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           exp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= exp))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "red")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Expenditure")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           cmp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4]))+
                                             geom_line(aes(y= inc,group = 1, colour = "Income"))
                                           + geom_line(aes(y= exp,group =1, colour = "Expenditure"))+
                                             xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Income (in lakhs)")+
                                             scale_color_manual("",
                                                                breaks = c("Income","Expenditure"),
                                                                values = c(
                                                                  "Income"="green", 
                                                                  "Expenditure"= "red"
                                                                ))+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           gprofit = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= gprofit))+
                                                 geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                 ylab("Gross Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           nprofit =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= nprofit))
                                                +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                  ylab("Net Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           plost =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= plost))
                                              +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                        fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                ylab("Profit Lost (in lakhs)")+
                                                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           pp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= pp))+
                                            geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                     fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                            ylab("Profit Percentage")+
                                            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           proftrend = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot()+
                                                   geom_line(data = as.data.frame(date[2:z]),
                                                             aes(x= Data[c(2:z),4] , y= proftrend,
                                                                 group = 1, color = slope > 0))+
                                                   xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Profit Trend")+
                                                   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
           ))})
  output$table <- renderTable(Data)}) #Display the choosen file details

    observeEvent(input$hplotit, {
             inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                         Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
             inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
             exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                         Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
             exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
             gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3] - Data[,2],
                                            Dummy2 = Data[,8] - Data[,7],
                                            Dummy3 = Data[,13] - Data[,12],
                                            Dummy4 = Data[,18] - Data[,17]))
             gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
             nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = (Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),
                                             Dummy2 = (Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),
                                             Dummy3 = (Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),
                                             Dummy4 = (Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22)))
             nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
             date <- as.character(Data[,4])
             h <- input$ploth
             switch(EXPR = h ,
                    inc2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(inc2), y = date,
                                                                    z = inc2, type = "heatmap",
                                                                    colorscale = "Earth")),

                    exp2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(exp2), y = date,
                                                                    z = exp2, type = "heatmap", 
                                                                    colors = colorRamp(c("red",
                                                                                         "yellow")))),

                    gprofit2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(gprofit2),
                                                                        y = date, z = gprofit2,
                                                                        type = "heatmap",
                                                                        colorscale="Greys")),

                    nprofit2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(nprofit2),
                                                                        y = date, z = nprofit2,
                                                                        type = "heatmap")) 
             )       
    })



      observeEvent(input$retable, {
        inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
        inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
        exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
        exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
        gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round(Data[,3] - Data[,2],2),
                                        Dummy2 = round(Data[,8] - Data[,7],2),
                                        Dummy3 = round(Data[,13] - Data[,12],2),
                                        Dummy4 = round(Data[,18] - Data[,17],2)))
        gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
        nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),2),
                                        Dummy2 = round((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),2),
                                        Dummy3 = round((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),2),
                                        Dummy4 = round((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22),2)))
        nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
        h <- input$ploth
        did <- cbind(Date = (as.character(Data[,4])),get(h))
        output$click <- renderTable(did)})

      observeEvent(input$clear, { 
                   did <<- NULL
                   output$click <- renderTable(did)
                   })
      output$Next <- renderPlot({
        event.data <- event_data(event = "plotly_click")
        vars <- event.data[["x"]]
        vars <- as.character(vars())
        inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
        inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
        exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
        exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
        gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round(Data[,3] - Data[,2],2),
                                        Dummy2 = round(Data[,8] - Data[,7],2),
                                        Dummy3 = round(Data[,13] - Data[,12],2),
                                        Dummy4 = round(Data[,18] - Data[,17],2)))
        gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
        nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),2),
                                        Dummy2 = round((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),2),
                                        Dummy3 = round((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),2),
                                        Dummy4 = round((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22),2)))
        nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
        h <- input$ploth
        did <- cbind(Date = (as.character(Data[,4])),get(h))
        if(is.null(event.data)) NULL else plot(x = as.character.Date(Data[,4]) ,y = did$vars)
      })

      }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Important Parts

```
Shiny.ui

tabPanel("Heatmap",
                       actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                       selectInput("ploth","Heatmap", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc2",
                                                                   "Expenditure" = "exp2",
                                                                   "Gross Profit" = "gprofit2",
                                                                   "Net Profit" = "nprofit2")),
                       actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                       plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                      fixedRow(column(3,actionButton("retable","Show Table")),
                               column(3,actionButton("clear","Clear"))),  
                       tableOutput("click"),
                       plotOutput("Next")

Shiny.server

output$Next <- renderPlot({
    event.data <- event_data(event = "plotly_click")
    vars <- event.data[["x"]]
    vars <- as.character(vars())
    inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
    inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
    exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
    exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
    gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round(Data[,3] - Data[,2],2),
                                    Dummy2 = round(Data[,8] - Data[,7],2),
                                    Dummy3 = round(Data[,13] - Data[,12],2),
                                    Dummy4 = round(Data[,18] - Data[,17],2)))
    gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
    nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),2),
                                    Dummy2 = round((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),2),
                                    Dummy3 = round((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),2),
                                    Dummy4 = round((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22),2)))
    nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
    h <- input$ploth
    did <- cbind(Date = (as.character(Data[,4])),get(h))
    if(is.null(event.data)) NULL else plot(x = as.character.Date(Data[,4]) ,y = did$vars, type = "o")
  })

  }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have an app ready and it works but the final step of plotting the next graph after the click is not working because of

```
Warning: Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I know the error is in

```
 event.data <- event_data(event = "plotly_click")
    vars <- event.data[["x"]]
```

Because i cant use the even_data input to call the columns. Please help in what i should do to convert it so that i can call the "vars" in the "did" data frame so that the final graph can be plotted. Please also tell if there is some other problem also. Thank You.

Some sample data

```
Comp_name <- c("Dum1")
Inc <- c(175.26,175.365,175.65,176.65,176.165,176.1685,175.56)
Exp <- c(175.48,174.53,174.165,173.1651,175.651,174.16541,176.65)
Date <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name,Inc,Exp,Date,Dates))
Comp_name1 <- c("Dum2")
Inc1 <- c(151.26,151.59,151.23,152.46,152.49,151.29,150.81)
Exp1 <- c(152.64,152.84,152.64,152.48,152.35,154.26,153.14)
Date1 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates1 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name1,Inc1,Exp1,Date1,Dates1))
Comp_name2 <- c("Dum3")
Inc2 <- c(160.45,161.25,163.56,165.25,163.59,160.89,161.26)
Exp2 <- c(160.19,160.78,162.15,164.89,165.24,163.25,162.48)
Date2 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates2 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name2,Inc2,Exp2,Date2,Dates2))
Comp_name3 <- c("Dum4")
Inc3 <- c(156.26,155.12,157.12,158.78,154.26,160.12,161.26)
Exp3 <- c(160.19,160.19,155.19,154.26,150.12,157.26,159.12)
Date3 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dates3 <- c(2018-06-01,2018-06-02,2018-06-03,2018-06-04,2018-06-05,2018-06-06,2018-06-07)
Dummy4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Comp_name3,Inc3,Exp3,Date3,Dates3))
Data <- cbind(Dummy1,Dummy2,Dummy3,Dummy4)
Data <- as.data.frame(Data)
```

Comment: Your example is currently not reproducible; the formatting is a bit off and we do not have access to your data. It will be much easier to help if you provide a reproducible example, for some tips on how to do that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable).

Comment: The problem is that the data is in .csv format and i cannot attch a file here. So i used just a part of the complete code@Florian

Comment: Please at least read the resource I provided first. There is ways on how to deal with that described there.

Comment: I added some sample data for you that i thought may be of same format. Though i could not solve your problem

Comment: Thank you @mrigankshekhar. Yes the data is in same format.

Comment: @Florian is any more change required after the sample help?

Comment: @rahulyadav Again, there is a format for the reproducible example in the link I provided. Please just read that, I am not going to write a summary of its contents here.

Comment: I have read that. The file.choose() are in places where no edit is not needed. The place that has the problem has no file.choose() or other computer specific data. I tried copying the data and running it. It gives no problem. @Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the x value directly into one place. Don't do it in two phases.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gplots)
library(plotly)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type="text/css",
             ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
             ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
  ),
  titlePanel("Creating a database"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("name", "Company Name"),
      numericInput("income", "Income", value = 1),
      numericInput("expenditure", "Expenditure", value = 1),
      dateInput("date", h3("Date input"),value = Sys.Date() ,min = "0000-01-01",
                max = Sys.Date(), format = "dd/mm/yy"),
      actionButton("Action", "Submit"), #Submit Button
      actionButton("new", "New")),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Download",
                           textInput("filename", "Enter Filename for download"),   #filename
                           helpText(strong("Warning: Append if want to update existing data.")),
                           downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download'), #Button to save the file
                           downloadButton('Appenddata', 'Append')),#Button to update a file )
                  tabPanel("Plot", 
                           actionButton("filechoose", "Choose File"),
                           br(),
                           selectInput("toplot", "To Plot", choices =c("Income" = "inc1",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp1",
                                                                       "Compare Income And 
                                                                       Expenditure" = "cmp1",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit1",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit1",
                                                                       "Profit Lost" = "plost1",
                                                                       "Profit Percent" = "pp1",
                                                                       "Profit Trend" = "proftrend1"
                           )),
                           actionButton("plotit", "PLOT"),
                           plotOutput("Plot")),
                    tabPanel("Heatmap",
                           actionButton("combine","Combine"),
                           selectInput("ploth","Heatmap", "Plot Heatmap Of", choices =c("Income" = "inc2",
                                                                       "Expenditure" = "exp2",
                                                                       "Gross Profit" = "gprofit2",
                                                                       "Net Profit" = "nprofit2")),
                           actionButton("hplotit","Plot Heatmap"),
                           plotlyOutput("HeatPlot"),
                          fixedRow(column(3,actionButton("retable","Show Table")),
                                   column(3,actionButton("clear","Clear"))),  
                           tableOutput("click"),
                           plotOutput("Next")
                           )
                  )
      )

    )
  )
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output){
  #Global variable to save the data
  Data <- data.frame()
  Results <- reactive(data.frame(input$name, input$income, input$expenditure,
                                 as.character(input$date),
                                 as.character(Sys.Date())))

  #To append the row and display in the table when the submit button is clicked
  observeEvent(input$Action,{
    Data <<- rbind(Data,Results()) #Append the row in the dataframe
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the output in the table
  })

  observeEvent(input$new, {
    Data <<- NULL
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)
  })

  observeEvent(input$filechoose, {
    Data <<- read.csv(file.choose()) #Choose file to plot
    output$table <- renderTable(Data) #Display the choosen file details
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename , ".csv", sep="")}, # Create the download file name
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(Data, file,row.names = FALSE) # download data
    })

  output$Appenddata <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$filename, ".csv", sep="")}, 
    content = function(file) {
      write.table( Data, file=file.choose(),append = T, sep=',',
                   row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE) # Append data in existing
    })

  observeEvent(input$plotit, {
    inc <- c(Data[ ,2]) 
    exp <- c(Data[ ,3]) 
    date <- c(Data[,4])
    gprofit <- c(Data[ ,2]- Data[ ,3])
    nprofit <- c(gprofit - (gprofit*0.06))
    z <- as.numeric(nrow(Data))
    plost <- gprofit - nprofit
    pp <- (gprofit/inc) * 100
    proftrend <- c(gprofit[2:z]-gprofit[1:(z-1)])
    slope = c(((proftrend[2:(z-1)]-proftrend[1:(z-2)])/1),0)
    y = input$toplot
    switch(EXPR = y ,
           inc = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= inc))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Income")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           exp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= exp))+
                                             geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                      fill = "red")+xlab("Dates")+
                                             ylab("Expenditure")+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           cmp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4]))+
                                             geom_line(aes(y= inc,group = 1, colour = "Income"))
                                           + geom_line(aes(y= exp,group =1, colour = "Expenditure"))+
                                             xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Income (in lakhs)")+
                                             scale_color_manual("",
                                                                breaks = c("Income","Expenditure"),
                                                                values = c(
                                                                  "Income"="green", 
                                                                  "Expenditure"= "red"
                                                                ))+
                                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           gprofit = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= gprofit))+
                                                 geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                 ylab("Gross Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           nprofit =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= nprofit))
                                                +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                          fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                  ylab("Net Profit (in lakhs)")+
                                                  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           plost =  output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= plost))
                                              +geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                        fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                                ylab("Profit Lost (in lakhs)")+
                                                theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),

           pp = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = Data, aes(x= Data[,4], y= pp))+
                                            geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                                                     fill = "blue")+xlab("Dates")+
                                            ylab("Profit Percentage")+
                                            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))),
           proftrend = output$Plot <- renderPlot(ggplot()+
                                                   geom_line(data = as.data.frame(date[2:z]),
                                                             aes(x= Data[c(2:z),4] , y= proftrend,
                                                                 group = 1, color = slope > 0))+
                                                   xlab("Dates")+ ylab("Profit Trend")+
                                                   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
           ))})
  observeEvent(input$combine, {
    Data <<- cbind(read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),read.csv(file.choose()),
                   read.csv(file.choose()))
    output$table <- renderTable(Data)}) #Display the choosen file details

    observeEvent(input$hplotit, {
             inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                         Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
             inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
             exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                         Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
             exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
             gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3] - Data[,2],
                                            Dummy2 = Data[,8] - Data[,7],
                                            Dummy3 = Data[,13] - Data[,12],
                                            Dummy4 = Data[,18] - Data[,17]))
             gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
             nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = (Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),
                                             Dummy2 = (Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),
                                             Dummy3 = (Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),
                                             Dummy4 = (Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22)))
             nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
             date <- as.character(Data[,4])
             h <- input$ploth
             switch(EXPR = h ,
                    inc2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(inc2), y = date,
                                                                    z = inc2, type = "heatmap",
                                                                    colorscale = "Earth")),

                    exp2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(exp2), y = date,
                                                                    z = exp2, type = "heatmap", 
                                                                    colors = colorRamp(c("red",
                                                                                         "yellow")))),

                    gprofit2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(gprofit2),
                                                                        y = date, z = gprofit2,
                                                                        type = "heatmap",
                                                                        colorscale="Greys")),

                    nprofit2 = output$HeatPlot <- renderPlotly( plot_ly(x = colnames(nprofit2),
                                                                        y = date, z = nprofit2,
                                                                        type = "heatmap")) 
             )       
    })



      observeEvent(input$retable, {
        inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
        inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
        exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
        exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
        gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round(Data[,3] - Data[,2],2),
                                        Dummy2 = round(Data[,8] - Data[,7],2),
                                        Dummy3 = round(Data[,13] - Data[,12],2),
                                        Dummy4 = round(Data[,18] - Data[,17],2)))
        gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
        nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),2),
                                        Dummy2 = round((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),2),
                                        Dummy3 = round((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),2),
                                        Dummy4 = round((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22),2)))
        nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
        h <- input$ploth
        did <- cbind(Date = (as.character(Data[,4])),get(h))
        output$click <- renderTable(did)})

      observeEvent(input$clear, { 
                   did <<- NULL
                   output$click <- renderTable(did)
                   })
      output$Next <- renderPlot({
        event.data <- event_data(event = "plotly_click")[["x"]]
        vars <- as.character(event.data)
        inc1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,2],Dummy2 = Data[,7],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,12], Dummy4 = Data[,17]))
        inc2 <- as.matrix(inc1)
        exp1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = Data[,3],Dummy2 = Data[,8],
                                    Dummy3 = Data[,13], Dummy4 = Data[,18]))
        exp2 <- as.matrix(exp1)
        gprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round(Data[,3] - Data[,2],2),
                                        Dummy2 = round(Data[,8] - Data[,7],2),
                                        Dummy3 = round(Data[,13] - Data[,12],2),
                                        Dummy4 = round(Data[,18] - Data[,17],2)))
        gprofit2 <- as.matrix(gprofit1)
        nprofit1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(Dummy1 = round((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) - ((Data[,3] - Data[,2]) * 0.06),2),
                                        Dummy2 = round((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) - ((Data[,8] - Data[,7]) * 0.10),2),
                                        Dummy3 = round((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) - ((Data[,13] - Data[,12]) * 0.18),2),
                                        Dummy4 = round((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) - ((Data[,18] - Data[,17]) * 0.22),2)))
        nprofit2 <- as.matrix(nprofit1)
        h <- input$ploth
        did <- cbind(Date = (as.character(Data[,4])),get(h))
        if(is.null(event.data)) NULL else plot(x = Data[,4] ,y = did[,vars], type = "o")
      })

      }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```