# R/Shiny : Color of boxes depend on select

Tags: css, r, web-applications, shiny, shinydashboard

I try to create dynamic boxes in shiny.
We can change the status (color) of the box with (status = "warning" or "info" etc.)
I would like to change the color of this box (dynamically) depend on the choice of select input like that :

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/32/2/1533638864-v1.png
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/32/2/1533638864-v2.png

The code looks like this :

```
SelectInput("s010102i", label = NULL, 
 choices = list("Value 1" = 1, "Value 2" = 2, "Value 3" = 3), 
 selected = 1) ,width = 12, background = "blue", status = "info")),                                column(4,
```

We need to change the "info" in status by a variable. But when I try to put variable in ui side, it does not work and when i pass by the server like output$s010102i... the status is not equals to "info" in the output but :

```
ERROR: Invalid status: <div id="s010102o" class="shiny-html-output"></div>. Valid statuses are: primary, success, info, warning, danger.
```

How can i put this dynamically ? And how to change the selected by a variable ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit -> Here an exploitable code to understand :

```
 library(shiny)
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(DT)


  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  ui <- fluidPage(

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader( title = "Simple Test"),

    dashboardSidebar(),      
    dashboardBody(          
    fluidRow(

           box(title = h3("S.01.01.02", style = "display:inline; font-weight:bold"),

             selectInput("s010102i", label = NULL, 
                         choices = list("Not good" = 1, "O.K" = 2, "Good" = 3), 
                         selected = 1) ,width = 12, background = "blue", status = renderUI("s010102o"))
                                                                              # I want a text or a variable here
                                                                              # Logically "danger", warning or success
           # If Not good is selected, i wan that the status (the color) go to red (danger)
    ))))



  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
  server <- function(input, output) {

    statut = c("danger","warning","success")


    output$s010102o <- reactive({  
      valueStatut = input$s010102i # Give 1 2 or 3
      s010102o =  statut[valueStatut] # give the value of the statut if "danger" the box changes to red 

    })
  }

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: [renderUI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.1.0/renderUI.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. But i have this error :
"ERROR: 'match' requires vector arguments". Match ?

Comment: Please provide [Shiny app reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080)

Comment: Code to test above. Thanks again.
The error is the same : renderUI("s010102o") should be 1,2 or 3 to work but I want a variable :)

Comment: Ideally, we would need `updateBox` and there is an issue filed at GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/287

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to create the whole box in the server using `renderUI` and just render it in the UI using `uiOutput`. You can do something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader( title = "Simple Test"),

    dashboardSidebar(),      
    dashboardBody(          
      fluidRow(
        uiOutput("s010102o")
      ))))



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  statut = c("danger","warning","success")

  output$s010102o <- renderUI({
    box(title = h3("S.01.01.02", style = "display:inline; font-weight:bold"),

        selectInput("s010102i", label = NULL, 
                    choices = list("Not good" = "danger", "O.K" = "info", "Good" = "success"), 
                    selected = 1) ,width = 12, background = "blue")})

  observeEvent(input$s010102i,{
    output$s010102o <- renderUI({
      box(title = h3("S.01.01.02", style = "display:inline; font-weight:bold"),

          selectInput("s010102i", label = NULL,
                      choices = list("Not good" = "danger", "O.K" = "info", "Good" = "success"),
                      selected = input$s010102i) ,width = 12, background = "blue",status = input$s010102i)
    })


  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But be careful as you are updating the box in which the input is.

Comment: It works fine and very quickly ! 
I'll test how heavy il will be.

Merci :)