# R Shiny .rmd - loop to generate HTML divs

Tags: html, r, loops, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to generate HTML items based on data inside a data.frame. The data.frame will be changing from a reactive value, so the loop needs to be reactive as well.

I am struggling with the logic. I found some examples in a shiny dashboard, but I am attempting to do this in a markdown file.

````
---
title: "test"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    css: "css/styles.css"
---

### {.flex-container}

```{r echo=FALSE}
renderText({
  df <-  data.frame(symbol = 1:10)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
     div(class="flex-box", style="background-color:#DeF7E9",paste0(df[i,"symbol"]))
  }  

})

```
````

My css file looks like:

```
.title {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.flex-box{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color:#808080;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;

}
```

I am new to R, so be kind..

Cheers, 
Sody

Edit: getting closer with:

```
reactive({

divClass = list()  
df <-  data.frame(symbol = 1:10)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
     divClass[i] = div(class="flex-box", style="background-color:#DeF7E9",paste0(df[i,"symbol"]))
  }  
output$myboxes <- renderUI(divClass)

})

uiOutput("myboxes")
```

this outputs a list of ten divs as text, like this: 
div div div div div div div div div div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about try this

````
### {.flex-container}

```{r echo=FALSE}
renderText({
divClass = list()  
df <-  data.frame(symbol = 1:10)
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
     divClass[i] = div(class="flex-box", style="background-color:#DeF7E9",paste0(df[i,"symbol"]))
  }  
divClass
})

```
````

Comment: does not render, warnings: Warning in divClass[i] = div(class = "flex-box", style = "background-color:#DeF7E9",  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how it is outputting. This is the closest I could find using shiny app logic (not rmd) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741473/r-shiny-renderui-in-a-loop-to-generate-multiple-objects

Comment: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: getting closer with your help, take a look at my edit above.