# Conditional filtering in datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I have a population and area-type columns in the data table where I want the user to do conditional filtering (say select population>15000 & area-type is planned). I am using a reactive function, the areatype is working while the population isn't reactive. I am thinking of using the observe function but I don't know. My question is how to make both reactive & include dependency. Code:

```
    #UI 
    ui<-fluidpage(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "popdensity", 
                                     label = " Population Per Km2:",
                                     choices = list(
                                       "< 15,000"=1, 
                                       "15,001 - 30,000"=2 , 
                                       ">30,000"=3
                                     ), 
                                     selected =list(1,2,3)
                                     ),


    selectInput(inputId = "area", 
                              label = " AreaType:",
                              choices = c(
                                "All",

                                unique(as.character(nakuru$AreaType))
                              ) 
                  ))

    #SERVER
server<-function(input,output)({
    output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({

        #filtering based on user selection

        dt<-reactive({
        df<-nakuru
         if(input$area!="All"){

          df<-df[df$AreaType==input$area,]

         }
        if(input$popdensity==1){
          df[df$PopDensity<=15000,]
        }
         if(input$popdensity==2){
          df[df$PopDensity>15000&df$PopDensity<=30000,]
        }
       if(input$popdensity==3){
          df[df$PopDensity>30000,]
        }

        df
        })
        DT::datatable(dt(),options = list(scrollX=TRUE))
      })
})
```

[Nakuru data](https://github.com/brynmwangy/Shiny-App-Demo/blob/master/nak3.csv)
  [SHINY APP LAYOUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpr8D.png)

Comment: what's the output you are hoping for?

Comment: Say if a user selects population >15000 & areatype==planned, the columns are filtered based on the user selection & output displayed on the data table.

Comment: Hi @brian, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable) for tips on  how to create a MCVE for Shiny. That will make it a lot easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see if this solves the issue. You really have to provide a minimum reproducible example, including the dataset using dput

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui<-fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "popdensity",
                                 label = " Population Per Km2:",
                                 choices = list(
                                   "< 15,000"=1,
                                   "15,001 - 30,000"=2 ,
                                   ">30,000"=3
                                 ),
                                 selected =list(2,3)
),

selectInput(inputId = "area",
            label = " AreaType:",
            choices = c(
              "All",unique(as.character(nakuru$AreaType)))
),
dataTableOutput("filtered_table")
)

#SERVER
server<-function(input,output){

  dt<-reactive({
    df<-nakuru
    print(head(df))
    if(input$area!="All"){
      df<-df[df$AreaType==input$area,]

    }
    str(df)
    df1<- df %>%  filter(Populationperkm2 < 15000)

    df2<- df %>%  filter(Populationperkm2 > 15000 & Populationperkm2<=30000)
    df3<- df %>%  filter(Populationperkm2>30000)
    temp<- data.frame()

    if(1 %in% input$popdensity ){

      temp<-rbind(temp,df1)

    }

    if("2" %in% input$popdensity){

      temp<-rbind(temp,df2)
    }
    if("3" %in% input$popdensity){
      temp<-rbind(temp,df3)
    }
 temp
  })
  output$filtered_table<-DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(dt(),options = list(scrollX=TRUE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the problem without a minimum reproducible example. But perhaps try this. Bring the reactive part outside of the `renderDatatable` portion

```
dt<-reactive({
    df<-nakuru
     if(input$area!="All"){

      df<-df[df$AreaType==input$area,]

     }
    if(input$popdensity==1){
      df[df$PopDensity<=15000,]
    }
     if(input$popdensity==2){
      df[df$PopDensity>15000&df$PopDensity<=30000,]
    }
   if(input$popdensity==3){
      df[df$PopDensity>30000,]
    }

    df
    })

output$table<-DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(dt(),options = list(scrollX=TRUE))
  })
```

Comment: This assumes nakuru is not a reactive dataset. This wont work if it is

Comment: You can download the dataset.I have only included the most important part of the code.I have tried your option still not working only the areatype responds to the user input while population doesn't.

Comment: Where have you provided the dataset?

Comment: Click on nakuru data

Comment: I am thinking of using observe function but not sure of how to implement it and if it will include reactivity in the population column.