# SelectInput for multiple valueBoxes

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for a way to have three separate valueBoxes respond to the same selectInput. My dataframe:

```
region        Diarrhea       Fever     ARI
Afghanistan   78.2          56.4       29.7
Boys          34.1          23.2       15.6
Girls         18.4          12.8       11.2
```

For selectInput I want Diarrhe, Fever and ARI as options, and I would like to see three Value boxes, one for Afghanistan, one for Boys and one for Girls with the value corresponding to input variable.
I cant seem to figure out how to this..

Thanks!

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Data", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12,
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(2, offset = 0, style = 'padding:1px;', 
                   selectInput(inputId = "selected_data",
                               label = "Indicator",
                               choices = overall[,c(2:4)]))
          )
        )
    ),
    uiOutput("value_box")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value_box <- renderUI({
    valueBox(input$selected_data,subtitle = "Afghanistan")

  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Margo, welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very good first question on SO with a good small example to make it clear what you are looking for. There are some small improvements you could make to future questions to get your questions potentially answered even quicker, such as including the libraries and the data needed to reconstruct your problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable/48343110#48343110) for some tips. Anyway, just small things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make separate `uiOutputs`, but a more concise approach would be to use `lapply` inside the `renderUI` to loop over your resulting `dataframe`. Note that I renamed your input to `selected_column` and I modified the options in the input.

A working example is given below, hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
overall = read.table(text = 'region        Diarrhea       Fever     ARI
Afghanistan   78.2          56.4       29.7
Boys          34.1          23.2       15.6
Girls         18.4          12.8       11.2', header=T)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Data", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12,
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(2, offset = 0, style = 'padding:1px;', 
                   selectInput(inputId = "selected_column",
                               label = "Indicator",
                               choices = setdiff(colnames(overall),'region')))
          )
        )
    ),
    uiOutput("value_box")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value_box <- renderUI({
    box(width=12,
    lapply(1:nrow(overall), function(i) {
      valueBox(overall[i,input$selected_column],overall[i,'region'])})
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

> EDIT: As requested in your comment, this would be an example on how to make this work with separate UI elements:

```
overall = read.table(text = 'region        Diarrhea       Fever     ARI
Afghanistan   78.2          56.4       29.7
                     Boys          34.1          23.2       15.6
                     Girls         18.4          12.8       11.2', header=T)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Data", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12,
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(2, offset = 0, style = 'padding:1px;', 
                   selectInput(inputId = "selected_column",
                               label = "Indicator",
                               choices = setdiff(colnames(overall),'region')))
          )
        )
    ),
    box(width=12,
        uiOutput("value_box1"),
        uiOutput("value_box2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$value_box1 <- renderUI({
    valueBox(overall[1,input$selected_column],overall[1,'region'])
  })

  output$value_box2 <- renderUI({
    valueBox(overall[2,input$selected_column],overall[2,'region'])
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for the suggestions on improving my question, and of course for the solution to my problem! Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad I could help :) Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/364979) to mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Certainly! If I am not asking too much of your time and wisdom - what would it look like if I were to use multiple uiOutputs responding to the same SelectInput, rather than looping through?

Comment: You're a hero! Thanks so much Florian