# Why is renderUI not rendering selectInput in chain of inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

So I have a chain of `selectInput()` that I need to render once we have the selection from the previous `selectInput()`. It seems to work fine, but the last one isn't render.

In my server.R file I have the following reactive expression and the renderUI expression:

```
  time_series_names <- reactive({
    req(input$ac, input$factor_type, input$sub_type1, cancelOutput = FALSE)
    #calls an external function to get choices for selectInput...never gets
    #called and I'm not sure why...
    tryCatch({get_names_of_factors(asset_class = input$ac,
                                   factor_type = input$factor_type,
                                   sub_type = input$sub_type1)},
             error = function(e){
               cat("Waiting on metadata to be selected...\n")
               NULL
             })
    })

  output$selectTimeSeries <- renderUI({
    browser()
    req(input$ac, input$factor_type, input$sub_type1, cancelOutput = FALSE)
    selectInput("var",
                label = "Time Series",
                choices = time_series_names(),
                multiple = TRUE)
    })
```

So you can see the chain of three `input$...` required but I'm not sure why I can't get the `output$selectTimeSeries` to render with `uiOutput` once I have everything selected. I thought since `time_series_name()` is reactive it would trigger the `renderUI` expression? I did make sure to write `uiOutput("selectTimeSeries")` correctly in my ui.R file.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, in the current format, it is difficult to answer your question. Please consider adding a reproducible example. For tips on how to do that, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable/48343110#48343110)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad question, I had a `req(input$sub_type1)` but that reactive value didn't exist (was supposed to be `req(input$sub_type)`).