# Shiny Module renderTable can't update with input variable change

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinymodules

I have a checkbox and a table in my code. What I want is when user check certain box, new column with corresponding name with be generated.

Ideal Case Example:

[image]

However, this is what I have with my code:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
lineGraphUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    checkboxGroupInput(ns("variable"), "Variables to show:",
                       c("black" = "black",
                         "white" = "white",
                         "asian" = "asian")),
    tableOutput(ns("datatbr"))
  )
}

lineGraph <- function(input, output, session) {
  da <- read.csv(file = "RaceByYearTemplet.csv", header = TRUE)  

  output$datatbr <- renderTable({
    da[c("year",input$variable), drop = FALSE]
  }, rownames = TRUE)
}
```

```
navBlockUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    tags$div(class = "tabPanel-plotBlock",
             tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                         tabPanel("Graph", lineGraphUI(ns("line"))),
                         tabPanel("Line", tablePlotUI(ns("table")))
             )
    ) 
  )
}

navBlock <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(lineGraph, "line")

  callModule(tablePlot, "table")
}
```

I think the problem might shiny module can not be update when the checkbox is checked? Because I have tried to put the same code directly in app.R and it works just fine(as it shows in the 'ideal case example' image above).

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable). Can you provide working code and some example data? Modules can be tricky, and they certainly require seeing the full code to help others test your app and see what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

This works like this:

```
lineGraphUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    checkboxGroupInput(ns("variable"), "Variables to show:",
                       c("black" = "black",
                         "white" = "white",
                         "asian" = "asian")),
    tableOutput(ns("datatbr"))
  )
}

lineGraph <- function(input, output, session) {
  da <- iris[1:5,]
  names(da) <- c("black", "white", "asian", "abcd", "year")

  output$datatbr <- renderTable({
    da[, c("year",input$variable), drop = FALSE]
  }, rownames = TRUE)
}

navBlockUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(
    tags$div(class = "tabPanel-plotBlock",
             tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                         tabPanel("Graph", lineGraphUI(ns("line")))
             )
    ) 
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  navBlockUI("xxx")
)
navBlock <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(lineGraph, "xxx-line")
}

shinyApp(ui, navBlock)
```