# Can a progress bar render random sentences?

Tags: r, shiny

I am testing the feasibility of generating random sentences from a list and rendering those in a `progressSweetAlert`. So far, I have been unable to get further than having the first randomly selected sentence post as the 'value' object.

What I am trying to achieve is, as the progress bar ... progresses, the randomly selected sentences render for a couple of seconds and then proceeds to the next string...such as...

"Eating bugs..."
"Watching paint dry..."
"Thinking big thoughts.."

Using the LaF package, I have succesfully created a list of sentencs and called it:

```
x<-c('Locating evil driods.',
     'Planting happy thoughts.',
     'Checking the water for bugs.',
     'Reading "A Tale of Two Cities" ',
     'Questioning the matrix.',
     'Generating apple clones.',
     'Discovering new things.')

writeLines(x, con="tmp.csv")
```

As per BDS masterly guidance, here is a working example :) :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(LaF)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Progress bar in Sweet Alert"),
  useSweetAlert(), # /!\ needed with 'progressSweetAlert'
  actionButton(
    inputId = "go",
    label = "Launch long calculation !"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$go, {
    x<-sample_lines("tmp.csv", 5)
    y <- paste(x, 1:length(x), sep = "")

    progressSweetAlert(
      session = session, id = "myprogress",
      title = y,
      display_pct = TRUE, value = 0
    )
    for (i in seq_len(50)) {
      Sys.sleep(0.1)
      updateProgressBar(
        session = session,
        id = "myprogress",
        value = i*2
      )
    }
    closeSweetAlert(session = session)
    sendSweetAlert(
      session = session,
      title =" Calculation completed !",
      type = "success"
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am hoping to get something not dissimilar from what you can see in these examples (https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/make-loading-screen-unity).

However, this is what I got:

[image: Progress1]
[image: Progress2]

Comment: you can improve your question by making it reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343080/how-to-convert-a-shiny-app-consisting-of-multiple-files-into-an-easily-shareable.

Comment: Hmm...I thought I included enough? I could paste the entire flow ofc BDS!

Comment: thats good, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you coul just use the `title`parameter?

You set `title = sentences[sample(length(sentences), 1)],`

`updateProgressBar` could read:

```
updateProgressBar(
  session = session,
  title = sentences[sample(length(sentences), 1)],
  id = "myprogress",
  value = i*10
)
```

Full example would read:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")


ui <- fluidPage(
tags$h1("Progress bar in Sweet Alert"),
useSweetAlert(), # /!\ needed with 'progressSweetAlert'
actionButton(
  inputId = "go",
  label = "Launch long calculation !"
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$go, {
  progressSweetAlert(
    session = session, id = "myprogress",
    title = "Work in progress",
    display_pct = TRUE, value = 0
  )


  sentences <- c('Locating evil driods.',
                 'Planting happy thoughts.',
                 'Checking the water for bugs.',
                 'Reading "A Tale of Two Cities" ',
                 'Questioning the matrix.',
                 'Generating apple clones.',
                 'Discovering new things.')

  for (i in seq_len(10)) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    updateProgressBar(
      session = session,
      title = sentences[sample(length(sentences), 1)],
      id = "myprogress",
      value = i*10
    )
  }
  closeSweetAlert(session = session)
  sendSweetAlert(
    session = session,
    title =" Calculation completed !",
    type = "success"
  )
})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks BDS! Small question - i am experimenting with the time rendered (sentences) by adjusting `Sys.sleep` but that (as you nkow) only prolongs the completion of the "Alert". Any ideas on how to get each to stay around 3s?

Comment: It depends of courseon the calculation time of the function you call. You could at least approximate it. I think we should open a new question for that.

Comment: Indeeed-o. Im going to run a couple of functions through it to see what it looks like. Thanks again!